# read csv file into 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

CSV File:

```
515.30,516.81
516.81,514.27
516.74,517.68
517.54,516.72
517.61,517.64
517.22,516.99
517.21,517.33
516.99,516.92
516.96,517.5
517.38,516.91
```

No blank lines in between.

My program so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSVRead
{
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception
    {
        double[][] test = new double[9][2];
        String[] testStr = new String[19];

        String delimiter = ",";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner("kort.csv");

        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            testStr = line.split(delimiter);
        }   

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            {
                test[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(testStr[2*i+j]);
            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<10; y++)
        {              
            for (int x=0; x<2; x++)
            {
                System.out.print(test[y][x] +" ");
            }
        }
    } //main()
} // CSVRead
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AEX2008kort.csv"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at CSVRead.main(CSVRead.java:26)
Java Result: 1

Comment: The `while (sc.hasNextLine())` seems pointless...if there are multiple lines in the text file, you're going to overwrite `testStr` with the last line anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? only read a specific number of csv entries? Read all csv entries and only save the most recent?

Comment: Have you checked what `testStr[2*i+j]` is returning? Seems it contains `kort.csv`, which, obviously, does not have a double in it to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("kort.csv"));
```

You want to parse the content of the file, not the String "kort.csv"

Comment: Nice catch. It's these little errors that tend to fool my head compiler.

Answer (score 0):

After you have done what Alex mentioned, you need to change the way testStr is being used. In your current code, testStr will always have the last line elements (517.38 and 516.91). What you probably want to do is to store the Double numbers in a List perhaps,

```
List<Double> mynumbers = new ArrayList<Double> ();
```

and use it later on to populate your 2D array. Once you have split the line into testStr, you should add these numbers to the list,

```
mynumbers.add(testStr[0]);
mynumbers.add(testStr[1]);
```

Finally, in the parseDouble method, instead of passing testStr you should pass your list:

```
mynumbers.get(index_you_want);
```